# Have characters (subscripts) in equation mode occupy the same width

Tags: math-mode, typewriter

Is there a way to make specific letters in equation mode have the same width? I could use the command `\texttt{}` outside the align environment but not in math mode. For instance, the script below generates the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{l,\text{h}}\hat{y}^t \odot m_l + \textstyle\sum_{i} \alpha^t_{l,i}\hat{y}^t_{l,i} \odot (1 - m_l) \\
    \hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{r,\text{h}}\hat{y}^t \odot m_r + \textstyle\sum_{i} \alpha^t_{r,i}\hat{y}^t_{r,i} \odot (1 - m_r)
\end{align}

\noindent
\texttt{your text - IN CAPITALS}\\
\texttt{lrlr text - IN CAPITALS}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I have a lot of such equations that need to be computed and read sequentially and i think it would be nicer if I could have at least specific letters occupy the same width. In the example above I would like the subscripts `l` and `r` have the same width or have the letter `l` have extra padding to match total width the letter `r` takes. I cannot use their capital letters.

Comment: Is the main aim to have the *terms* align horizontally? So that the operators line up?

Comment: Specifying explicit alignment is probably better. Otherwise you got a little awkward space after the `l`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is better to align the operators rather than get "accidental" alignment by forcing same width characters.

I also restricted textstyle to just the summation not the rest of the expression.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    \hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{l,\text{h}}\hat{y}^t &&\odot m_l &&+ \mathop{\textstyle\sum_{i}} \alpha^t_{l,i}\hat{y}^t_{l,i} &&\odot (1 - m_l) \\
    \hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{r,\text{h}}\hat{y}^t &&\odot m_r &&+ \mathop{\textstyle\sum_{i}} \alpha^t_{r,i}\hat{y}^t_{r,i} &&\odot (1 - m_r)
\end{alignat}

\noindent
\texttt{your text - IN CAPITALS}\\
\texttt{lrlr text - IN CAPITALS}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I agree with David Carlisle that you have an [XY problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

But, here are some answers to the X problem.  The `\texttt` command also works in math mode if you use `amsmath`, which nearly all math papers do.  The `unicode-math` package additionally provides `\symtt` for the Unicode mathematical typewriter alphabet.  (Note that neither is supposed to be synonymous with ordinary variables.)  Finally, you could calculate the maximum width of the subscripts and put a `\scriptstyle i` inside a `\mbox` whose width is the same as the widest subscript.