# alignat incorrect spacing

Tags: alignat

I am coming from this thread [Have characters (subscripts) in equation mode occupy the same width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683833/have-characters-subscripts-in-equation-mode-occupy-the-same-width/683877#683877) to make my equation occupy the same width. The solution is to use alignat. Now I add in 2 more equations above and the spacing goes wild. How do I fix this ? Ive tried a bunch of random things but they all end up looking like garbage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    \hat{y}_{\Psi}^t &= \Psi(h^t_\text{h}) \\
    \hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s,i} &= \Phi([\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t \odot m_s,x_i^t];\text{BPS}_i) \label{eq:doublenets} \\
    \hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{l,\text{h}}\hat{y}^t &&\odot m_l &&+ \mathop{\textstyle\sum_{i}} \alpha^t_{l,i}\hat{y}^t_{l,i} &&\odot (1 - m_l) \label{eq:update1} \\
    \hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{r,\text{h}}\hat{y}^t &&\odot m_r &&+ \mathop{\textstyle\sum_{i}} \alpha^t_{r,i}\hat{y}^t_{r,i} &&\odot (1 - m_r) \label{eq:update2}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is the places where you put (and do not put) the `&`.

Comment: so what should i do ? i just want the 2 equations below to additonally align at \odot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hide the width of the entries in the first rows, eg

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{4}
    \hat{y}_{\Psi}^t &= \Psi(h^t_{\mathrm{h}})\hspace{-\textwidth} \\
    \hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s,i} &= \Phi([\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t \odot m_s,x_i^t];\mathrm{BPS}_i)\hspace{-\textwidth} \label{eq:doublenets} \\
    \hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{l,\mathrm{h}}\hat{y}^t &&\odot m_l &&+ \mathop{\textstyle\sum_{i}} \alpha^t_{l,i}\hat{y}^t_{l,i} &&\odot (1 - m_l) \label{eq:update1} \\
    \hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{r,\mathrm{h}}\hat{y}^t &&\odot m_r &&+ \mathop{\textstyle\sum_{i}} \alpha^t_{r,i}\hat{y}^t_{r,i} &&\odot (1 - m_r) \label{eq:update2}
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

I also fixed `\text` which should not be used here, to `\mathrm`, I missed that last time.

Comment: Jeez, i would have never thought of that solution. Many thanks you are very kind. Latex is so unintuitive and is something I will never get better at especially since I only visit it once a year when writing up my work....

Comment: @Kong I wouldn't say this was that latex-specific, `alignat` is just a table, you would see same in html or other tables if you put a large entry in column 2 that column gets wider in all rows, as your image showed.

Comment: Why not use `\rlap` on the post-`=` segment of the second line?

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\rlap{$\displaystyle{} ...$}` or `\mathrlap{\displaystyle...}` from `mathtools` would work but  I thought hspace was simpler here

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IEEEeqnarray` provided by the `IEEEtrantools` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\newcommand{\hup}{\mathrm{h}}
\newcommand{\tsum}{\mathop{\textstyle\sum}\nolimits}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rLLLL}
\hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{l,\hup}\hat{y}^t &\odot m_l &+
  \tsum_{i} \alpha^t_{l,i}\hat{y}^t_{l,i} &\odot (1 - m_l) \\
\hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{r,\hup}\hat{y}^t &\odot m_r &+
  \tsum_{i} \alpha^t_{r,i}\hat{y}^t_{r,i} &\odot (1 - m_r)
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
And another one
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rLLLL}
\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t &= \Psi(h^t_{\hup}) \\
\hat{y}^t_{\Phi,s,i} &
  \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{4}{L}{=\Phi\bigl([\hat{y}_{\Psi}^t \odot m_s,x_i^t];\mathrm{BPS}_i\bigr)}
\label{eq:doublenets} \\
\hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{l,\hup}\hat{y}^t &\odot m_l &+
  \tsum_{i} \alpha^t_{l,i}\hat{y}^t_{l,i} &\odot (1 - m_l)
  \label{eq:update1} \\
\hat{y}^t &= \alpha^t_{r,\hup}\hat{y}^t &\odot m_r &+
  \tsum_{i} \alpha^t_{r,i}\hat{y}^t_{r,i} &\odot (1 - m_r)
  \label{eq:update2}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}


\end{document}
```

Note that `\text{h}` and `\text{BPS}` are wrong and `\text` should be `\mathrm`. I also provided a shorthand for the text style `\sum`.

The column type `L` means left alignment with an empty atom at the beginning, so the spacing around the initial binary or relation symbol is correct.

[image]